# Macro enabled worksheet object in powerpoint auto update

Tags: vba, object, macros, powerpoint, worksheet

I have a linked Macro enabled `worksheet` object in PowerPoint presentation that I would like to refresh every 5 seconds.

The actual Excel sheet that the object is linked to has a macro that refreshes the data every 5 seconds.

If i right click the object, I have the option to open the Macro enabled `worksheet` object, when opening the object, excel opens the linked file as "worksheet in blahblah.pptx" and because there is a macro in the excel file to refresh data every five seconds, the PowerPoint slide updates also.

But, when I run the slide show the excel file closes.

So what I would like to do is a VBA code to refresh one slide only (in slideshow mode) every 5 seconds with the data that is in the Macro enabled worksheet object.

Can somebody help me how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the code you already tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible but not trivial. You'd need to set up application events in PowerPoint (initialisation can be done via an application add-in load or via the ribbon onLoad event) to start a Windows API timer on the SlideShowBegin event which triggers the macro to refresh the slide and then use the SlideShowEnd event to stop the timer. As the solution isn't a couple of lines of VBA but a module, a classes, several procedures, Windows API declarations and Ribbon XML code I haven't developed a complete solution for free in response to this directional answer.